# What post hoc test to use following Fisher's exact test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, post-hoc, fishers-exact-test

I performed Fisher's exact test on a 4*2 table in SPSS, and I got a significant difference (P= 0.010) and I wonder what is the post hoc test to use following that?

Is it the adjusted standardized residuals?
and if I want to calculate the P value from each adjusted standardized residuals, how can I do that?

Comment: You can test all six 2*2 tables with the same procedure and then apply a generic multiplicity correction like Holm's. There might exist more powerful approaches though.

Comment: Fisher's exact test is not very accurate so why use it?

Comment: Hi Michael M. Could you please explain how to convert the 4*2 table to six 2*2 tables?

Comment: Hi Frank Harrell.  I used Fisher's exact test because the assumptions of Chi Square test were violated.